# Build failure after updating maven version to 3.5.3

Tags: maven

I am a nascent in Maven world. Any help is highly appreciated.
I am trying to build existing java application (earlier built using maven 2.2) using Maven 3.5.3 and is currently blocked in below issue:

**Error:**
*

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.alcatel.in.osp.services.icc.api.plugin:updateHighLevelApi:5.8:run
>   (default) on project High-level-api: Unable to parse configuration of
>   mojo
>   com.alcatel.in.osp.services.icc.api.plugin:updateHighLevelApi:5.8:run
>   for parameter basedir: Cannot find 'basedir' in class
>   com.alcatel.in.osp.services.icc.api.plugin.updateHighLevelApi -> [Help
>   1]

**Pom.xml goes as below:**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.alcatel.in.osp.services.icc.api.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>updateHighLevelApi</artifactId>
        <version>5.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <basedir>${basedir}\..\updateHighLevelApi</basedir>
          <domain>parameterDomains.properties</domain>
          <include>includedBeans.properties</include>
          <exclude>excludedMethods.properties</exclude>
          <mandatory>mandatoryAttributes.properties</mandatory>
          <targetPath>\..\HighLevelApi\src\main\java\com\alcatel\in\osp\services\icc\api\services</targetPath>
          <webTargetPath>\..\HighLevelApiWS\src\main\java\com\alcatel\in\osp\services\icc\api\web</webTargetPath>
          <packageName>com.alcatel.in.osp.services.icc.api.services</packageName>
          <webPackageName>com.alcatel.in.osp.services.icc.api.web</webPackageName>
          <targetedJar>
            <!-- <param>cre2-10-2-DR4-HF1102-obs30-NLL-api.jar</param> -->
            <param>ICC58_INTDEV07_NLLAPI.jar</param>
            <param>ratingengine</param>
            <param>RatingEngine</param>
          </targetedJar>
        </configuration>       
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>      
      </plugin>
```

**and code goes as below:**

```
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.jar.*;

/**
 * Launch updateHighLevelApi.
 * @goal run
 */
public class updateHighLevelApi extends AbstractMojo {

    private static int modulo = 3;
    private static String lib = "\\lib";
    private static String conf = "\\config";
    private static String platform = "platform";

    /**
     * Base Directory
     * @parameter basedir
     */

    private static String basedir;

    /**
     * File Name for include beans
     * @parameter include
     */

    private static String domain;

    /**
     * File Name for handled domain
     * @parameter domain
     */

    private static String include;

    /**
     * File Name for excluded methods
     * @parameter exclude
     */

    private static String exclude;

    /**
     * File Name for mandatory attributes
     * @parameter mandatory
     */

    private static String mandatory;

    /**
     * Directory for HLA
     * @parameter targetPath
     */
    private static String targetPath;
    /**
     * Directory for HLA web
     * @parameter webTargetPath
     */
    private static String webTargetPath;

    /**
     * Package Name for HLA 
     * @parameter packageName
     */
    private static String packageName;

    /**
     * Package Name for HLA web
     * @parameter webPackageName
     */
    private static String webPackageName;

    /**
     * Array Name for the jar file   
     * @parameter targetedJar
     */
    private static String[] targetedJar;
    ..
```

The code used to work well when maven version was 2.2.. After migrating to maven 3.5.3, I am getting above error in one of my application;s plugin.

Regards,
Ruchi

Comment: clean **.m2** folder and try to build again

Comment: Migrate the plugin to Maven 3.X compatibility cause it looks it is not compatible with Maven 3.X...

Comment: Night Programmer... Local repository path in my maven's settings.xml is: <localRepository>D:\All_data\Work\Code\HLA_Maven_3.5_setup\repository</localRepository>.. You mean I should remove the complete subfolders or just D:\All_data\Work\Code\HLA_Maven_3.5_setup\repository\com\alcatel\in\osp

Comment: khmarbaise: Can you please guide how can i migrate my plugin?

Comment: @RuchiGupta delete complete repository in your case D:\All_data\Work\Code\HLA_Maven_3.5_setup\repository, better remove complete directory, and also check all  plugin compitible version in Maven 3.5.3, and update that version in pom.xml(thats how you can migrate plugin)

Comment: @Afgan I tried deleting the repository and updating pom.xml, but it dint work. Another thing i noticed... if i remove parameter from variable basedir, then i build is successful......private static String basedir = ""; But below code fails...
 
 /**
  * Base Directory
  * attherate parameter basedir
  */
 
 // private static String basedir = ""; Can you pls help

Comment: @RuchiGupta can you eleborate more about basedir, i am not getting you properly